# Which models for suitable for integer values of independent and dependent variables

Tags: model, count-data

The data set has independent and dependent measurements that are events, and can be counted.  What input / output models are appropriate for integer values?  So far I've tried linear regression, and classification trees.  I would like to try a hidden or partially observable Markov model, but I'm not sure how to set it up.

Please ask me for additional details that would be beneficial to clarify the question.  I have previously asked for guidance on this effort, but the prior question was not answered, possibly due to providing only context information.

Ref: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122150/event-level-driven-response-modeling

I can add more detail, but I need guidance on what type of information is beneficial.  I'm trying to predict the occurrence of 28 different events, the events can either be measured by counting, or by duration per occurrence.  The independent data is all countable events, but some of the events are exceedance of a threshold and could be represented as a ratio of max value to threshold.

The 28 events to be predicted occur after the independent events.  The data has been rolled up into records that include the independent events, and the following dependent events.  But, the dependent events may depend on an independent event from a previous record.  I am approximating the effect of lag by including the min, max, and count from the previous N records (N is on the order of 3).

My background is in testing and simulation of vibration, controls, and response.  But I don't have experience in modelling discrete events.  I have the data in R, and am currently using the caret package to evaluate different modelling approaches.

A crude example of the data is available at this link where the question was asked about generating frequency tables for sequential events.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981149/r-how-to-determine-sequences-and-frequency

The data set has about 12 independent parameters, but about 400 independent events.

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for count data models (google that term). Poisson regression or Negative Binomial regressions are standard examples of Generalized Linear Models. Your favorite statistics package should be able to deal with those. In R, for instance, look at `glm()`.

If you have time series ("events" suggests time series to me), you may want to look at integer autoregressive models, or INAR.

You may get better answers if you could be a bit more specific about your situation and about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: In this cases, there is a "probability" of the independent event "causing" the dependent events.  I added more info to the question above...

Comment: Hm. Can you edit your question to give a minimal toy example illustrating the features of your problem?

Comment: Ok, I add a link to a different question about the frequency of previous events.  That data is conceptually similar to my data.  But, here I'm asking a more general question, what are the types of approaches for this type of data.  The data represents the operational and maintenance characteristics of a fleet.  The maintenance is not necessarily performed right away, so there is a variable lag between independent operating characteristics and dependent maintenance actions.